# Access multiple lines from a text using Regular Expression and iterate in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file which is converted from an invoice/PO pdf file. I need to extract the Product details from it using Regular expression. The problem I am facing is I can easily extract a single product detail. However, since a number of invoices are parsed(not at a time) I cannot predict the number of products there will be in an invoice. So how do I determine how much product will be there and iterate through it and take all of the products' details.

#### Below given is a sample invoice text with single product:

```
Item SKU Product Desc. Qty UOM 
1 _L180.0001352879 Clam Tuatua Medium 20- 1.00 cs
34pc/Kg 15kg/CS
```

#### Below given is a product with multiple products:

```
Item SKU Product Desc. Qty UOM
1 L465.0001354266 Yoghurt Passionfruit Organic 4.00 PC
Vegan 1kg
2 L465.0001354264 Yoghurt Plain Organic Vegan 4.00 PC
1kg
```

Now the regular expression and code I'm using for this is below:

```
line_match = re.compile(r'UOM\s\d\s+([\w.]+)\s([\w\s\-]+[\s])([0-9.]+)\s([\w]+)\n([\w\/\s]+[\n])')

line = line_match.search(text)
    
print("Product description : " + line.group(2) + line.group(5))
print("Quantity : " + line.group(3))
```

Comment: Do you have these `<br/>` really in your file or were to trying to put a newline here in `StackOverflow` ?

Comment: Sorry for that. I was trying to put a newline

Comment: If you can use the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), you could use `(?:UOM\s|\G(?!^))\d\s+([\w.]+)\s([\w\s-]+\s)([0-9.]+)\s(\w+)\n([\w/\s]+\n)` See https://regex101.com/r/fvyUxK/1

Comment: Thank you, this works. But how do I extract each individual matches from this?

Comment: @zuestech I have added an answer with an explanation how to get the matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and use the `\G` anchor to get iterative matches.

*Pattern*

```
(?:UOM\s|\G(?!^))\d\s+([\w.]+)\s([\w\s-]+\s)([0-9.]+)\s(\w+)\n([\w/\s]+\n)
```

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `UOM\s` Match UOM and whitespace char
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Asset the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close group
- `\d\s+` Match a digit and 1+ whitespace chars
- `([\w.]+)\s` Capture **group 1** Match word chars or dots and whitespace char
- `([\w\s-]+\s)` Capture **group 2** Match word / whitespace chars or `-` and ending whitespac char
- `([0-9.]+)\s` Capture **group 3** Match digits or `.` and whitespace char
- `(\w+)\n` Capture **group 4** Match word chars and newline
- `([\w/\s]+\n)` Capture **group 5** Match word / whitespace chars or `/` and newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lApPuX/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##lZFfS8MwFMXf@ymufUrY1rVdN3UgPkwQ2aaTOUGMSmizLmjTktyggt99pvujYvHBvCTce/M7l3Oqd1yVqrdey6IqNYIWuXjzvIojCq3gBLRPToeLqykzH@ycnB48UsoyZlrknr0GDy3KTP1ipvPQYoaS@7BzvCuzV3eputtlpi4p3/NQGHwyqB2Z@BcoCpiPFzDTZWZThDNh0gCu8R1qRTcPP44fwdMkOgqDMAyjXj8@OjyG0Qsv4MZytBymIpO2gDjsQORmIDUNQi@p0u44h6j/nHdH80b/3wtNkkF/t08SDwZwV@Yr62yccWNkqZbaSoQrnXMlU0jqrWajBuZWuD5Ez3mjE/8SSL4FXrhUX@Qt4S/@lkw9r@CYroSpU61jDpZSZdLlTHZxt2Efjxtelho2Hy5t0d6@wEkKZQuhOQqyo9HhRq3SUiHx98ZlzjgtK3QmwBB8aG0JQa5LW5GY/ir0Kf1JubZcoXSuN7/2KF2vPwE)

*Example code*

```
import regex

pattern = r"(?:UOM\s|\G(?!^))\d\s+([\w.]+)\s([\w\s-]+\s)([0-9.]+)\s(\w+)\n([\w/\s]+\n)"

test_str = ("Item SKU Product Desc. Qty UOM\n"
            "1 _L180.0001352879 Clam Tuatua Medium 20- 1.00 cs\n"
            "34pc/Kg 15kg/CS\n\n\n\n"
            "Item SKU Product Desc. Qty UOM\n"
            "1 L465.0001354266 Yoghurt Passionfruit Organic 4.00 PC\n"
            "Vegan 1kg\n"
            "2 L465.0001354264 Yoghurt Plain Organic Vegan 4.00 PC\n"
            "1kg\n\n\n")


matches = regex.finditer(pattern, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print("Product description : " + match.group(2) + match.group(5))
    print("Quantity : " + match.group(3))
```

*Output*

```
Product description : Clam Tuatua Medium 20- 34pc/Kg 15kg/CS
Quantity : 1.00
Product description : Yoghurt Passionfruit Organic Vegan 1kg
Quantity : 4.00
Product description : Yoghurt Plain Organic Vegan 1kg
Quantity : 4.00
```